# Why does my component not get focus?

Tags: java, focus

I am running an applet, and am trying to focus on a component outside of the init method. I have tried using requestFocus and requestFocusInWindow. Both of these return true, as do isDisplayable, isVisible, and isFocusable, but calling hasFocus right after this returns false. The component just doesn't show up in the applet.

Here is the method called by the event listener (when the user clicks 'begin battle'), trying to focus on the component:

```
private void beginBattle(){
    BattleSequence bs = new BattleSequence(..);
    remove(pnlInit);
    remove(pnlOOB);
    remove(pnlBattle);
    add(bs);
    bs.setVisible(true);
    bs.requestFocusInWindow(); //this returns 'true'
    bs.setBounds(0, 0, bs.getSize().width, bs.getSize().height);
    bs.init();
    }

public class BattleSequence extends RavelSequence

public abstract class RavelSequence extends Applet implements KeyListener, FocusListener
```

Why is the focus request denied? If there is more code that is relevant, I can post it!

*****EDIT:
Adding the mouse listener worked to get focus to the component, but I don't want to have the user need a mouse to control the game. I changed the declaration of RavelSequence to extend Container instead of Applet, and everything works peachy.
bs.hasFocus still returns false, but the key events are handled appropriately.

Comment: What kind of component is BattleSequence?

Comment: It extends an abstract class which extends Applet.

    public class BattleSequence extends RavelSequence
    public abstract class RavelSequence extends Applet implements KeyListener, FocusListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call it on event dispatch thread.

Comment: Would I do that by putting the beginBattle method into the actionPerformed method instead of where it is now?

Comment: Just try    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               bs.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });

Comment: Ok, this also works, and is a bit more quaint than adding a mouse listener. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a MouseListener to the component in question, and request focus in the mouseClicked() method.

Comment: Ok, this works and gets focus to the BattleSequence. Is there any other way? The whole program is keyboard oriented, and I would like to leave the mouse out of it if possible. 
Also, why does this work?

Comment: Also, it doesn't work for the first click, but it does for the second. Can someone explain why this is?